# How to show satellite imagery in the Bing Maps control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dictionary

I want to set a Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Map from the default roads and labels mode to satellite mode. How would this be accomplished?

Comment: May I ask why would this be closed? I'm sorry if I don't understand what's wrong with the question. Its not very detailed because the task described does not need any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Phone 7 applications, you can set the `Mode` property to `Aerial` or `AerialWithLabels` to get the satellite view.

In Windows Phone 8 applications, you have the `CartographicMode` property (details [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)). You can set it to one of the value `MapCartographicMode` enum (details [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.mapcartographicmode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)), which can be: `Road`, `Aerial`, `Hybrid` or `Terrain`.

Comment: In a Windows 10 UWP app, you can set the MapControl Style="AerialWithRoads", etc. Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 is saying it's "invalid markup", even though Intellisense offered up the property and the list of possible values. But it builds and runs as expected.